# How to I make this Ul element go below a Div element?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="Sidebar">
        <div id="User-Icon"></div>
        <ul>
            <li a href="#">Home</li>
            <li a href="#">Home</li>
            <li a href="#">Home</li>
            <li a href="#">Home</li>
            <li a href="#">Home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Dashboard">
    </div>

    <div id="UserFeed">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  * {
        Font-Family: Arial;
        Margin: 0;
        Padding: 0;
    }
    
    #dashboard {
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    #Sidebar {
        background-color: #5c5c5c;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }   
    
    #Dashboard {
        background-color: #999999;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    #UserFeed {
        background-color: #D9D5D6;
        height: 100%;
        width: 30%;
    }
    
    #User-Icon {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    ul {
        
    }
    
    
    li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

My goal here is to move the ul under my User-Icon in a centered matter, if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using things like Clear: left; for the ul, Float: bottom; but I just couldn’t get anything to work. I would like to know more about this so if you can, I would like the explanations to be a bit detailed for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add flex-direction and align items

```
#Sidebar {
        background-color: #5c5c5c;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
        display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
       align-items:center
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried with z-index ?

try this

```
ul {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: The Ul seems to disappear when I put in that code

Answer (score 1):

Change this within sidebar

```
#Sidebar {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

It will keep the formatting you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Although, if you want the user icon to be centered within the sidebar, but retain its location on the vertical axis, then add this to #User-Icon:

```align-self: center;
```

along with the code I wrote above for #Sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

[image: How to I make this Ul element go below a Div element]

If this is what you are looking for please use `flex-flow: column;align-items: center;` for the parent Element. display flex is a little bit complex. you should read [the doc](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) carefully. Here is the updated CSS for you.

```
#Sidebar {
 background-color: #5c5c5c;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: center;
}
ul {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```